# Area Charts Using Google Analytics API - Uncaught TypeError Cannot Read 'libraries' of undefined

Tags: javascript, api, charts, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics Embed API to place custom analytics on our site. I have successfully authorized the API on our site and created numerous line and pie charts. I am now trying to make an Area chart to display some data, but I keep getting the same error and I'm not sure why. The error I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'libraries' of undefined
```

From my understanding typically *undefined* means something is missing, in this case *libraries* I presume. Yet, I'm not sure how or why.

I am loading the API using:

```
<script async src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
```

My Script to create the Area chart is as follows:

```
<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
}(window,document,'script'));

gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  /**
   * Authorize the user with an access token obtained server side.
   */
  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    'serverAuth': {
      'access_token': '##############################################'
    }
  });


var primaryChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
      ids: 'ga:79361233',
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:browser',
      'start-date': '2016-04-04',
      'end-date': '2016-05-03'
    },
    chart: {
      container: 'primaryChart',
      type: 'AREA',
      options: {
        isStacked: true,
        width: '100%',
        height: '200',
        tooltip: {
            trigger: 'focus'
        }
      }
    }
  });
  primaryChart.execute();

});
</script>
```

I'm using the same setup for my Line and Pie charts, they just use LINE or PIE, respectively, for their *type* parameter in the *chart* section. Yet, those work. I've searched and I've been hard pressed to find anything except for information at Google's Chart API which is a little different setup than I'm using since I'm querying the Analytics API directly.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to: [Built-in Components Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#data-example)
the only supported values for `chart.type` are:
**LINE, COLUMN, BAR, TABLE, and GEO**
Please note that the values are case-sensitive, even if you spelled it right.